# Bootstrap 4 Sticky footer adding a lot of padding

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I am trying to create a website with Bootstrap 4 on Apache (Ubuntu Linux), the footer is sticky as expected, but if only have a small amount of information on the page I have to scroll past a lot of white space to see the footer.

I don't understand how to get the footer to behave more like the demo on the website, the only difference is that I have a navbar as well as a footer.

Advice would be greatly welcomed please, I am pulling my hair out over this.

**Minimum working code**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" class='h-100'>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" >

    <style>
      .footer
{
    margin: 0;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 22px;
    background-color: #13294a;
}

        body
        {
            min-height: 75rem;
            padding-top: 5rem;
        }
    </style>

    <title>Secure Shed Project</title>
</head>

<body class="d-flex flex-column h-100">
    <header role="banner">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExample04" aria-controls="navbarsExample04" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExample04">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
    </header>

    <main role="main" class="flex-shrink-0 pb-2">
        <div class="container">
            <h1>Website coming soon</h1>
        </div>
    </main>

    <footer class="footer mt-auto">
        <div class="container-fluid text-center text-md-left text-white">
            <div class="text-center">
                <p class="copyright m-0">© 2020 Copyright A.N.Other</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in your code is this min-height on the body element. First, you will remove that. Then you will see that your footer is not sticky anymore. There are many solutions for that and I will recommend you this one:

Instead of using 75rem, you should use this `min-height: 100vh;`.

Answer (score 1):

The thing is you are forcing a minimum height for your body

Remove this line in your style:

```
min-height: 75rem;
```